# How to give customize transition effect at hover image

Tags: jquery, css

I've some links at my page. That links have background image. When, someone hover on that image, a new image will have to come with a transition effect. I need [this transition effect](http://www.creativetier.com/products/modern-menu-3/horizontal.html) At this link, when you click on the drop down menus, a colorful background will come from **left to right**. I want when someone hover on my image, my hover background image will come like that way. But, instead of coming **left to right** like that drop down menu it should be come from **bottom to up**. Is there any way to do it by CSS3? If not, can you please help me by giving jquery downloadable sample? If I have to use jQuery to do this, I hope, you'll help me to generate that as I ain't expert at jQuery.

My Sample HTML code:

```
<a href="dataMining.html" class="dMining">Data Mining</a>
<a href="distributedSystems.html" class="dSystem">Distributed Systems</a>
```

Sample CSS code:

```
.dMining, .dSystem {
   width: 139px;
   height: 70px;
   float: left;
}
.dMining {
   background: url('../images/dataMiningNormal.png');
}
.dMining:hover {
   background: url('../images/dataMiningHover.png');
}
.dSystem {
   background: url('../images/distributedSystemNormal.png');
}
.dSystem:hover {
   background: url('../images/distributedSystemHover.png');
}
```

Sample Normal Image:

[image]

Sample Hover Image:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine the images into a [css sprite](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/). Then just animate the background-position.

```
#my-menu-item { transition: background-position 1s }
#my-menu-item:hover { background-position: 0px -[menuItemHeight]px }
```